# Group a column depend on the result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've one basic question : I tried to create a query in SQL :

```
Select Date, Status From Table
```

My result is, for example ,

```
2016-06-07   FAILED
2016-06-07   FINISH OK 
2016-07-07   FINISH OK
2016-07-07   FINISH OK
```

Is it possible to tell If the status is 'FAILED' from the 2016-06-07, print just one line with the failed status. If it's just finish ok, print finish ok. 
I would like this result :

```
2016-06-07   FAILED
2016-07-07   FINISH OK
```

Thanks,

EDIT: 
I have just 2 status : FAILED and FINISH OK

more and more dates and results :

```
2016-06-07   FAILED
2016-06-07   FINISH OK
2016-06-07   FINISH OK
2016-06-07   FINISH OK
2016-06-07   FINISH OK

 2016-07-07   FINISH OK
 2016-07-07   FINISH OK
 2016-07-07   FINISH OK
 2016-07-07   FINISH OK
 2016-07-07   FINISH OK

2016-07-08    FINISH OK
2016-07-08    FINISH OK
2016-07-08    FINISH OK
2016-07-08    FAILED
2016-07-08    FINISH OK
```

I would like to have:

```
2016-06-07   FAILED
2016-07-07   FINISH OK
2016-07-08   FAILED
```

If I have one FAILED status in a date, I would like to print 'FAILED', but if I do not have any 'FAILED' status, I would print 'FINISH OK', Is it better?

Comment: please add more data for more dates

Comment: Add some dates with different status and tell what should be the result

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I update the post. Is it bette?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a `CASE` with conditional agregation.

The first `COUNT` is just to show you how work. This will count the number of fails on each date group.

Then the following `CASE` check if there are 1 or more fail

```
 SELECT Date,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'FAILED' THEN 1 END) as total_fails,           
        CASE WHEN Count(CASE WHEN Status = 'FAILED' THEN 1 END) > 0 
             THEN 'FAILED'
             ELSE 'FINISH OK'
        END as Status 
FROM Table
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: I think @MisterPositive is the most simple answer if you only have two status. But mine is more generic and can be adapt to multiple cases.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I can add more and more status if I need with your solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can use TOP 1 WITH TIES with ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES  
                    [Date], 
                    [Status] 
From [Table]
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY [Status] ASC)
```

Output:

```
Date        Status
2016-06-07  FAILED
2016-07-07  FINISH OK
2016-07-08  FAILED
```

Comment: Super ! It's working too ! What's the best to use? your or the result just below (with the count and a case)?

Comment: You probably should test it both using `EXPLAIN`

Comment: I don't think you will get any time/performance difference using any of given solutions. :) Personally I will choose the one suggested by MisterPositive, the simple one, yet, should work OK.

Comment: Usually this kind of query's are used when you need to get F.e. first/last status on some date (it needs to be some columns that will represent the order of rows, like datetime or identity). If you add some new status, F.e. `AVAILABLE`, better use solution of Juan the rest solutions will fail.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
Select Date, MIN(Status) 
From Table 
Group By Date
```

Comment: Use `MIN` instead, you want `FAIL` be the first choice.

Comment: Working too  ! I thought MAX and MIN was just for number? What's the logic when we have String? Thanks

Comment: Is the same , but use alphabetical order `'A' < 'B'` and `'A' < 'AA'`

Comment: Thanks @JuanCarlosOropeza

Answer (score 1):

Though I am using the same approach as above but I think this can be more simpler using COUNT DISTINCT as below:

```
SELECT date, 
    CASE WHEN COUNT( DISTINCT status)>1 
         THEN 'FAILED' 
         ELSE 'FINISH OK' 
    END AS status
FROM table
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: This will generate double rows for datas with both values.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have updated my answer please check, hope you will find it more simpler and easy to understand.

Answer (score -1):

Would you like to group by date or by status?

```
SELECT Date, Status FROM Table GROUP BY Date
```

or

```
SELECT Date, Status FROM Table GROUP BY Status
```

If you have a group by, you can also have some summary information. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: This won't work, you need to group by both status and date if you need those in Select